# IMG in table cell, force max-size but maintain aspect ratio and responsiveness

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I have a table with an image in the first cell and text in the next.  The page will be viewed with all devices, so I need to keep responsiveness (and the table).

Everything seemed to work - images were centered, are responsive, etc. BUT, some images are just too tall.  So I set a max height, but now the images lose aspect ratio.

If I set the width and height to auto I lose responsiveness, and I can't find a solution that keeps the aspect ratio, sets max width and height and still maintains responsiveness, any pointers?

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
  max-width:800px;
  }

table td {
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:solid black 2px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
table td:first-child {
  width: 50%;
  }
table td img {
  max-width:180px;
  max-height:70px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" width="100%" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Blah Blah
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="100%"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      Blah Blah
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Does it work when you set a max-width, a max-height *and* set the width to auto. It seems to work in your snippet.</del>

**Edit: Version 2**

1. Is this the effect you want?
2. Can you move the img to the background of the td?

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
  max-width:800px;
  }

table td {
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:solid black 2px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
table td:first-child {
  width: 70%;
  max-width:180px;
  max-height:70px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(http://goo.gl/QrKCc);">
    </td>
    <td>
      Blah Blah
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(http://goo.gl/QrKCc);">
    </td>
    <td>
      Blah Blah<br />
      A forced second line to increase the height
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png)"> 
    </td>
    <td>
      Blah Blah
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It loses the responsiveness.  If you open the snippet in full screen then shrink your browser window down you can see the images no longer scale with the table size.  Plus the images start at native size and don't scale to the size of the table cell.  You can see in your snippet that the beaker pic is tiny, far smaller than the cell would allow.

Comment: @Dave_K Right, let's try that again. Have I at least understood what you're trying to achieve in the updated snippet?

Comment: I will give that a try, I think it might work out for me, thanks!!

Comment: I had to end up setting a min-height in the td to keep some taller images from getting too small but it worked out.  Thanks!